# How to reverse the stack order of ListView in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I need to build `ListView` of images. I expect the former should above the latter like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
class PostsList extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => ri !== r2
    });
    this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows([
        'img_1.jpg',
        'img_2.jpg',
        'img_3.jpg',
        'img_4.jpg',
        'img_5.jpg',
      ])
    }
  }
  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    console.log(typeof rowID);
    var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    var height = width * 3 / 4;
    var marginTop = (rowID === '0') ? 0 : -height/2;
    var source;
    if(rowID === '0') {
      source = require('../assets/img/img_1.jpg');
    } else if(rowID === '1') {
      source = require('../assets/img/img_2.jpg');
    } else if(rowID === '2') {
      source = require('../assets/img/img_3.jpg');
    } else if(rowID === '3') {
      source = require('../assets/img/img_4.jpg');
    } else if(rowID === '4') {
      source = require('../assets/img/img_5.jpg');
    }
    return (
      <Image
        style={[styles.image, {width, height, marginTop}]}
        source={source}
        resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}
        />
    );
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
    );
  }
};
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

I know why this result, but I don't know how to reverse the stack order.

The data used here is fake, the real data will be a JSON file gotten by Ajax from another site.

Comment: Would reversing the data in the array before passing it to the datasource handle your issue? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: @NaderDabit not really. The data in array is ordered by date. I need to keep the order

Comment: try adding increasing zIndex to Image in renderRow function.

Comment: @divyenduz I don't think React Native supports zIndex?

Comment: @BrickYang: You are right, does this help, http://w3z.in/71f | tried flex-order ?

Comment: `flex-order` is not supported in React Native either

Comment: I don't think there will be an easy solution for this if you want to use `ListView` - RN Views are stacked in the order they are placed in the virtual UI tree, and ListView will always do it sequentially. If you only have a handful of items, you can render them manually without ListView in reverse order

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same request before, this is the key of the code I used (with the `react-native-invertible-scroll-view` package):

```
// `https://github.com/exponent/react-native-invertible-scroll-view`
...
import InvertibleScrollView from 'react-native-invertible-scroll-view';
...
this.state = { dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows([...].reverse()), ... }
...
<ListView renderScrollComponent={props => <InvertibleScrollView {...props} inverted />} ... />
...
```